# Multiple External Style sheets?

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to added a pop-up login screen using downloaded code. However the problem is the CSS file that comes with it conflicts with my exiting one.

Is there any way to have a style sheet just apply within a set of div tags or any other method to make this work? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a style sheet only apply within div (or any other) tags, but you could put your login code within a div, give it a specific id (say 'login') and then place #login before all the styles in the login CSS. This will make them only applicable within that div.

So, if for example your login CSS has a line:

```
form { border: none; }
```

it would become:

```
#login form { border: none; }
```

...and the same for every other entry. That's the easiest way I can think of - assuming of course you can't just have the pop-up load a separate HTML file and not include your main CSS.

Comment: And by the way, I should add this is not what anyone would call best-practise. That would be to combine the CSS files & rename the conflicting styles.

Comment: No worries mate, everyone has to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inherited CSS Classes for example -

```
.newParentClass .theConflictClass{
    /*Override unnecessary CSS properties and use the one you wanted*/
    /*In case if this doesn't work you can fallback to "!important" */
    border: 1px solid #f00 !important;
}
```